# Google Compute Engine API Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to access *Google Compute Engine Instances*, then I active *Google Compute Engine API*, but how to retrieve an API key, between *server key* and *browser key*, which one should I create ?

Comment: are you using any programming language, or you want to access the API from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you're [using OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) to authenticate, there're different kind of credentials that you can use, such as web server applications, installed apps, client-sid apps, etc. You need to find out which one you need. 
In the Developers Console, you can [create the credentials](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2) that you might need. At the provided links you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods when it comes to authenticate your project to Google API's, You will find the details in page [1] below. Logging to a Compute Engine instance using the UI will use the third method 'Service Account Key' where you don't have to put any action as by default it will use your Compute Engine default service account.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key